# Sending const char* through UDP server

Tags: python, c++, sockets, udp

I am trying to implement a basic UDP socket in my code to send a string. Created an UDP server in C++ to send sort of a "hello world" and a client in Python to receive it. For this, I'm using G4G's example as base, only slightly modified:

```
#define PORT xxxx

void initializeUDP(int stop) {

    int sockfd;
    const char *hello = "Hello from server.\n";
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

    //Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA data;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsOk = WSAStartup(version, &data);
    if (wsOk != 0) {
        cout << "Cannot start Winsock! " << wsOk;
        return;
    }

    // Creating socket and binding with address
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);


    if (::bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int len;

    len = sizeof(cliaddr);  //len is value/result 

    while (globalVariableNameInPortuguese == 0) {
        sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, 1024, 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, len);
    }

    closesocket(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();

}
```

Also created these few lines to try to receive this string as a client in Python:

```
import socket

bufferSize = 1024

ip = "localhost"
port = xxxx
UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPClientSocket.connect((ip, port))
while True:
    message, address = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

    print(message)

UDPClientSocket.close()
```

The C++ code executes normally but I am uncertain whether it's actually doing what it should. However, if I set the IP in the Python code as "localhost" it gets stuck in recvfrom, and if I set the IP to 0.0.0.0 it gets WinError 10049. Not sure on what I'm doing wrong and how I should proceed to actually get this string.

Comment: Low-hanging fruit: Never ignore a return code in network programming (and think twice in all other programming). Check the return value from `sendto` to make sure the message was sent.

Comment: In the Wonderful World of Windows, `socket` returns a `SOCKET` which probably isn't an `int` on your system. If `SOCKET` is an unsigned integer, testing for < 0 probably won't be that helpful. Test against `INVALID_SOCKET`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It is giving "77776160".

Comment: That's not `INVALID_SOCKET`, so it looks like the `socket` call turned out OK. `bind` should have blown up anyway if the `sockfd` was bad. Errr. that's assuming the 77776160 is the result of the `socket` call. If that's the return from `sendto`... That would be one big mother of a message.

Comment: Hmmm. Speaking of...  You've told `sendto` you're sending 1024 bytes, and `hello`'s nowhere near that long. That's a bad thing to do. `sendto` is reading past the end of the buffer `hello`'s pointing at and Crom only knows what will happen as a result. Fix that mistake and see if you still have a bug.

Comment: Oh, while trying to reply quickly I ended getting the wrong return. Genius here (and still a newbie/noob for that matter). It is returning -1 in fact. Thanks for helping me to spot where the error is.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, `SOCKET` is unsigned on Windows.

Comment: -1 should be the `int` version of `INVALID_SOCKET`. Check [`WSAGetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror) to get the error code for what really went wrong. [Look up the code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) or use [`FormatMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage)to turn the error code into something easier to understand. Probably easier to look up the code.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSanders . It's got some conditional compilation on my machine, with one version one signed and one unsigned. Currently going unsigned here, but that's hardly proof it's always going to.

Comment: @user4581301 Interesting.  I'm using an older SDK (to maintain compatibility with XP) and in that it's unconditionally #defined as a `UINT_PTR`.

Comment: Using WSAGetLastError I got error 10047. Will look up the code.

Comment: Address family not supported. Didn't expect that.

Comment: Feeling a bit dumb right now. `cliaddr` was never set to anything useful , but used as the destination address in the `sendto` call.

Comment: Since I cannot tag a comment as an answer: user4581301 comment about cliaddr solved my problem and it is the answer, in case someone else happens to have this issue. Thank you.